# Get sum of multiple hh24:mi values using Loop

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to sum up the total working hours served between a specific date criteria. I've retrieved working hours of each day . Now I want to iterate over a range of date and sum up working hours and minutes.

Here is the method which I am trying to develop :

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_Working_hrs_Total (ecd in number,start_dt in DATE,end_dt in date,stdin IN VARCHAR2,stdout in VARCHAR2)
RETURN varchar2 AS
--
hrs   varchar2(1000);
temp_date date;
--
BEGIN

temp_date :=start_dt;

while temp_date <=end_dt
LOOP

select olphrm.get_std_hrs(ecd,temp_date,stdin,stdout)--It will return the working hours of date passed for example 8:30 i.e. 8 hours 30 minutes
into hrs from dual;--I want to get the count of Total working hours in this variable

temp_date :=temp_date+1;--switch to next day
END LOOP;

        return hrs;         

END;
```

How can I achieve the total working hours and minutes in a format like 16:30 i.e. sixteen hours and 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION GET_Working_hrs_Total (ecd in number,start_dt in DATE,end_dt in date,stdin IN VARCHAR2,stdout in VARCHAR2)
RETURN varchar2 AS
--
v_hours number(3,0) := 0; -- We'll put hours in here
v_mins  number(6,0) := 0; -- An mins in here
hrs   varchar2(1000);
temp_date date;
--
BEGIN

temp_date :=start_dt;

while temp_date <=end_dt
LOOP


select t-_number(to_char(olphrm.get_std_hrs(ecd,temp_date,stdin,stdout), 'HH24'), '999') + v_hours
into v_hours
from dual; -- Add new hours to old hours



select to_number(to_char(olphrm.get_std_hrs(ecd,temp_date,stdin,stdout), 'MI'), '999') + v_mins into v_mins  from dual; -- Add new mins to old mins

temp_date :=temp_date+1;

END LOOP;

v_hours := v_hours + floor(v_mins / 60); -- Add mins to hours

v_mins := mod(v_mins, 60); -- and ditch the hours from mins

hrs:= to_char(v_hours, '999') ||':'||to_char(v_mins,'99'); -- create the varchar to return

        return hrs;         

END;
```

Comment: it's not working because a char value cannot be added to a number value.

Comment: @AlinaAnjum see edit, I have added a `to_number()` around the `to_char()`. It's not pretty, but it should work

Answer (score 1):

After some of the changes in @JohnHc's answer:

The following code worked for me :

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_Working_hrs_Total (ecd in number,start_dt in DATE,end_dt in date,stdin IN VARCHAR2,stdout in VARCHAR2)
RETURN varchar2 AS
--
v_hours number(3,0) := 0; -- We'll put hours in here
v_mins  number(6,0) := 0; -- An mins in here
hrs   varchar2(1000);
temp_date date;
--
BEGIN

temp_date :=start_dt;

while temp_date <=end_dt
LOOP

SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM to_timestamp(olphrm.GET_Working_hrs(ecd,temp_date,stdin,stdout), 'hh24:mi') ) + v_hours
into v_hours from dual; -- Add new hours to old hours


SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM to_timestamp(olphrm.GET_Working_hrs(ecd,temp_date,stdin,stdout), 'hh24:mi') ) + v_mins  
into v_mins from dual;-- Add new mins to old mins


temp_date :=temp_date+1;

END LOOP;

v_hours := v_hours + floor(v_mins / 60); -- Add mins to hours

v_mins := mod(v_mins, 60); -- and ditch the hours from mins

hrs:= to_char(v_hours, '999') ||':'||to_char(v_mins,'99'); -- create the varchar to return

        return hrs;         

END;
```